# can't make tab bar hidden when using container views

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

My app uses view controllers each containing 2 container views as intermediaries between a tab bar controller and navigation controllers. This is for the purpose of managing a menu that is embedded in one of the container views in each intermediary.

I need to hide the tab bar (aka bottom bar).

I have tried sending `setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES` to every view controller, and I have tried selecting "hides bottom bar on push" in the storyboard for every VC.

Why aren't these things working? I assume it must be something about my architecture:

[image: story board]
As you can see, the navigation controllers are embedded within container views whose VCs are linked to the tab bar controller.

How can I hide the tab bar in this situation?

Comment: Is the container view necessary in the first place? You can just embed the navigation controller in the VC that are linked to the tab bar controller.

Comment: of course i have it for a reason. there are two containers in the embedded VCs. a smaller one that is covered up by the visible one embeds the menu, seen at bottom left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed: has to do with the optional toolbar that can be added to a navigation controller, not the tab bar. I think that if you add the line self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES; to the initial controller in each tab (the one with the container view), it will hide the tab bar. I think though, that it will leave a space at the bottom where the tab bar was. I'm not sure what the best way to fix that would be. Perhaps, if you're hiding the tab bar, you shouldn't be using a tab bar controller at all.

Comment: Okay, thanks, that's all accurate... including the part about the bar at the bottom that is apparently unavoidable. It's going to take way more effort/code to replace the tab bar controller with a dummy controller that presents/dismisses/keeps track of an array of VCs, but I guess that's what I'll have to do.

Comment: Ahh finally found an answer that explains how to successfully remove the tab bar and the black box: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903569/hide-uitabbar-in-ipad-application

Comment: @mkc842, I wonder if Apple will have a problem with you mucking around in the tab bar controller's subviews? I know they won't accept using private methods, I don't know about private views (and by private, I mean ones without any api to access them without searching through the hierarchy).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, guess I better do some research. It seems crazy that they don't make it easy to hide a tab bar, since a tab bar controller adds substantial functionality and can be manipulated without the built-in UI.

Comment: @mkc842, yeah, I agree. I don't understand why hiding a navigation bar automatically expands the content controller's view, but doing the same thing with a tab bar controller doesn't.